# Сортировка двусвязного списка: не инициализированный элемент

Tags: c, сортировка, двусвязный-список

Здравствуйте! Ни как не могу сделать сортировку с помощью перестановки указателей (Пробовал по разному). С простой перестановкой данных работает идеально, никаких ошибок, а вот с указателями появляется не инициализированный элемент. Указатели правильные (Вывод данных работает и сначала, и с конца). Возможно где-то проблема при считывании из файла. Все остальные функции работаю правильно. Ссылка на полный код: https://pastebin.com/FahxDfpA

```
int SortElements(){
int i,j=1;
struct BusPark *StartPtr;
if(NumberOfBuses==1)
{
    printf("\nВ списке всего один элемент!");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    while(j!=0)
    {
        j=0;
        StartPtr = List.Head;
        for(i=0;i<NumberOfBuses;i++)
        {
            if(StartPtr==List.Tail)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(StartPtr->RouteNumber > StartPtr->Next->RouteNumber)
            {
                j++;
                TransferPtr(StartPtr,StartPtr->Next);
            }
            StartPtr = StartPtr->Next;
        }
    }
}
return 0;}


void TransferPtr(struct BusPark *LeftElement,struct BusPark *RightElement){
if(LeftElement==List.Head)
{
    List.Head=RightElement;
    LeftElement->Next=RightElement->Next;
    RightElement->Previous=LeftElement->Previous;
    RightElement->Next=LeftElement;
    LeftElement->Previous=RightElement;
}
else if(RightElement==List.Tail)
{
    List.Tail=LeftElement;
    LeftElement->Next=RightElement->Next;
    RightElement->Previous=LeftElement->Previous;
    RightElement->Next=LeftElement;
    LeftElement->Previous=RightElement;
}
else
{
    LeftElement->Next=RightElement->Next;
    RightElement->Previous=LeftElement->Previous;
    RightElement->Next=LeftElement;
    LeftElement->Previous=RightElement;
}}
```

Считывание из файла:

```
void DownloadFromFile(struct BusPark *Address){
FILE *DownloadPtr;
struct BusPark *Temporary=NULL;
if((DownloadPtr=fopen("data.txt","r+b"))==NULL)
{
    printf("\nНевозможно открыть файл data.txt!");
    exit(2);
}
do {
    if (Address == NULL) {
        Address = (struct BusPark *) malloc(sizeof(struct BusPark));
        if (Address == NULL) {
            printf("\nПамять не была выделена!");
            exit(1);
        }
        List.Head = Address;
        fread(Address, sizeof(struct BusPark), 1, DownloadPtr);
        Address->Previous = NULL;
        Address->Next = NULL;
    } else {
        List.Tail=Address;
        Address->Next=NULL;
        Temporary=(struct BusPark *)malloc(sizeof(struct BusPark));
        if(Temporary==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nПамять не была выделена!");
            exit(1);
        }
        fread(Temporary, sizeof(struct BusPark), 1, DownloadPtr);
        Address->Next=Temporary;
        Address->Next->Previous=Address;
        Address=Address->Next;
    }
    NumberOfBuses++;
}while(!feof(DownloadPtr));
NumberOfBuses--;
fclose(DownloadPtr);}
```

Comment: Вот здесь лежит работающий пример (без чтения из файла) https://pastebin.com/eZ2HSmuf Можете редактировать на свой вкус.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Задавайте вопросы если что-то непонятно. Да, у вас Windows похоже,  код можно ещё упростить и сделать более понятным.

Comment: Вот здесь немного упрощённая версия (заменён `offsetof()` на явный кастинг, что, правда, накладывает ограничение на структуру данных, а именно поле списка должно быть всегда первым, как и указано в комментариях) https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy